# Reference Request: Manifold theory when $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by a complete ordered field

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, nonarchimedian-analysis

Manifolds are typically defined as follows:
A topological space $M$ is called a manifold, if for all $x\in M$, there exists an open set $U \ni x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

One could replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by another complete ordered (not necessarily Archimedean) field.

Schneider does so in his book *$p$-Adic Lie Groups*, developing the theory on manifolds over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ , and similar fields. 
Scheider makes this remark in the introduction:

> The fundamental difference is that the $p$-adic notion has no geometric content. As we will see, a paracompact $p$-adic manifold is topologically a disjoint union of charts and therefore is, from a geometric standpoint, completely uninteresting.

Is there a reference developing the theory for manifolds/lie groups/lie algebras say over the hyper-reals $\mathbb{R}^*$, or Levi-Civita fields, or other various non-Archimedean fields?

Comment: What do you mean with complete? If you mean Dedekind-complete, then you are out of luck, since there is no other such field.

Comment: @Wojowu, when someone refers to a non-Archimedean ordered field that is complete, is referring to the convergence of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @Chilote What metric are we considering though? The hyperreal field, for instance, is not metrizable.

Comment: @Wojowu In an ordered field $X$ you use the order topology induced by intervals in $X$: a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ is convergent to $x\in X$ if and only if for every open interval $I\subset X$ containing $0_X$, $x−x_n\in I$ for $n$ large enough. Similarly, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy if and only if for every open interval $I\subset X$ containing $0_X$, $x_m−x_n\in I$ for $n$, $m$ large enough.  Even when the ordered field is not metrizable, the order topology coincides with the topology induced by the natural Krull valuation on the ordered field

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but every ordered field besides $\mathbb{R}$ is totally disconnected, so I would expect the situation would be the same as over the $p$-adics: every paracompact manifold is a disjoint union of charts.